# css relative positioning not working in chrome

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have a problem with relative positioning in Google Chrome
The following code works fine in IE but not in Chrome.
Relative positioning is relative to the normal position of an element. 
The normal postion of the red box is right under the black box. 
If I add a 10% space the red box should appear 10% under the normal position.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hTKm8/)

Html

```
 <body>
 <div id="outer">
     <div id="inner1">
     </div>
     <div id="inner2">
     </div>
 </div>
 </body
```

Css

```
 #outer
 {
     position:absolute;     
     left:20%;
     right:20%;
     bottom:20%;
     top:20%;
     background-color:Blue;
  }

  #inner1
  {
      position:relative;
      width:20%;
      height:20%;
      background-color:Black; 
   }

   #inner2
   {
       position:relative;
       top:10%;   
       width:20%;
       height:20%;
       background-color:Red; 
   }
```

Comment: The parent Element need a `Width` - and `height` so you can use the width in `%` . **Solution 1)** - give the parent element a width & height. **Solution 2)** - give the red box a `margin-top:__px`

Comment: What is it you what it to look like exactly? because it looks ok to me http://jsfiddle.net/WrKk9/

Comment: It's really annoying while it works in Firefox = =

Comment: @man It's because in op's case, the dimension is specified by assigning both top and bottom. If it's a normal parent with only top and auto height, the problem occurs.

Answer (score 9):

For relative positioning to work the parent should have a size:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

[check the result in **this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zsg5x/3/)

Comment: Thanks, that works fine. But still there is the fact that chrome is the only browser that needs the width and height values for the containers for relative positioning to work. I understand top,bottom,.. as offset values with respect to the edge of a parent(absolute) or normal position(relative) and not as referring to the height or with of the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just realized myself now, what the problem of this is:

- the % for the top value is always referring the height of the parent element. Since you didn't set a height it is zero; if you set a height on the parent element everything is working as you wished...

see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qVU4Y/), i just added

```
height: 60%
```

to the parent css.

Comment: the problem is that when you add width and/or height values it works in Chrome to. But when you use the top, bottom, right and left values with absolute positioning is specifies the width and height values. I you math is wrong in your % values you get conflicting specifications. Beside that, if I specify a width and a height in the outer container and a left value,all in % values. I get a space between the black an red box in both IE and Chrome but the dimensions of the blue box are different.